# Flex Builder 3 design view, css not being applied

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I have Flex Builder 3 installed on two Windows machines and the same project on both of them. On one computer, the CSS styles I defined are shown in design view; on the other computer they are not applied. Is there any reason why it might not work on one?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the preferences under Flex/Editors/Design Mode? That has a skin rendering option, could that be it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when I first switch to design view the CSS is not applied until I hit the refresh button.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler probably uses by default the "Use the server's SDK" (Coldfusion??)
Right click the Project and select "Properties", select "Flex Compiler" and then select the correct SDK version. It has to be 3.x to be able to use the design view for CSS files.